# Setting elegantly similar statements without repeating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am using the next code in JavaScript to set classes for id,each time I want only one `div` would be with border class:

```
 if (counter) {
            $('#car1').addClass('border');
            $('#car2').removeClass('border');
        }
        else {
            $('#car2').addClass('border');
            $('#car1').removeClass('border');
        }
```

`counter` Its just a bool variable,Could be anything...

I wonder,can I do it more elegantly?

Comment: what is `counter`, and why would you both add and remove the same class on the same element ?

Comment: The code makes no sense to me. You add and remove the same class (border) in the same element, meaning that you will not have the class border anywhere anytime.

Comment: It seems, you want to set `border` on `#car1` and remove it from `#car2`…

Comment: If you have only two elements, there's nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: The code is fine, there's no need to complicate things when it's all nice and readable and works like intended.

Comment: Sorry guys,fixed it...yeah I want remove it from car1 and add it to car2, so only one div will have this class. About the counter its just a parameter that i check if it's true, it could be anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `counter` is a boolean, you can use it as a switch for toggleClass:

```
$('#car1').toggleClass('border', counter);
$('#car2').toggleClass('border', !counter);
```

-- [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) ->

> .toggleClass( className, switch )
>
> "switch" : Boolean A Boolean (not just
> truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class should be added or
> removed.

Answer (score -2):

How about a case statement

```
switch(counter)
{
  case 1:
   $('#car1').addClass('border');
   $('#car2').removeClass('border');
   break;
  case 2:
    $('#car2').addClass('border');
    $('#car1').removeClass('border');
   break;
  default:
   ....
}
```

Comment: It's the same idea I think...even more code

Comment: elegance = clarity, to me.  For novice programmers, maintainability = clarity = elegance.

Comment: And it doesn't even work the same way. In the original code the first block is executed if `counter` is truthy and the second block if it's falsy. You can't (and shouldn't) use a switch statement to test for that. (Granted, the variable name is misleading.)